# Algebraicity of Pusieux series

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, power-series, roots

I was reading about valued fields recently, and while trying to understand the formal power series field, I came up with a seemingly simple problem that bothers me a lot:

I am aware of the [Newton-Pusieux Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41101/puiseux-series-over-an-algebraically-closed-field) that a Puiseux series forms an algebraically closed field. However, I can't really do myself or find in the literature a proof of the fact that the field of a Pusieux series $P(K)$ is algebraic over $K((t)).$

I am especially curious if the fact that $P(K)$ is algebraic over $K((t)).$ could be proved without the Newton-Pusieux Thm. Any help would be appreciated.